# Wait for user response to geolocation prompt, then submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, geolocation

I have a button that users can click to use their location to find places nearby. How can I write the if/else statements to prompt the user to allow access to their location, wait for a response, then either submit the form or cancel out if they deny it?

```
<button id="submit_latlng" class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Use Current Location</button>
```

```
$('#submit_latlng').click(function() {
        getLocation(),
        $('#geo-loc-form').submit()
    })

    function getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                getPosition,
                positionError
            )
        }

        function getPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('user_lat').value = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById('user_lng').value = position.coords.longitude;
        }

        function positionError(error) {
            if (error.PERMISSION_DENIED) alert('Location services are off. Please enable location services, or use zip code search.');
                showError('Geolocation is not enabled.');
        }

    };
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I use. The user will be prompted by its web browser like this:

[image]

The first block is what you do if the user grants permission, and the second block *function(error)* is what you do if the user denies permission.

```
function getCoordinates()
{
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
    var lat = location.coords.latitude;
    var lng = location.coords.longitude;
    console.log("Location permission granted");
    console.log("lat: " + lat + " - lng: " + lng);
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log("Location permission denied");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following:

```
$('#submit_latlng').click(function() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                getPosition,
                positionError
            )
        }

        function getPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('user_lat').value = position.coords.latitude;
            document.getElementById('user_lng').value = position.coords.longitude;
            $('#geo-loc-form').submit();
        }

        function positionError(error) {
            if (error.PERMISSION_DENIED) alert('Location services are off. Please enable location services, or use zip code search.');
                showError('Geolocation is not enabled.');
        }

    });
```